# Does the real part of a complex line integral represent some kind of work done?

Tags: complex-analysis, physics, intuition, contour-integration, line-integrals

I am currently learning complex analysis and I am trying to interpret complex line integral in terms of physics concepts, such as force and energy. In particular, I want to know if the real part of a complex line integral represents the work done required to move along the curve.

This is because for a curve $\gamma (t)$, and a function $f=u+iv$, we have:

$$\int_{\gamma }f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma}(u,-v)\cdot dr +i\int_{\gamma}(u,-v)\cdot N dt$$

If we define the vector field $g=(u,-v)$, we can rewrite it as:

$$\int_{\gamma }f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma} g \cdot dr +i\int_{\gamma} g \cdot N dt$$

So we have:

$$
\textbf{Re}\left [\int_{\gamma }f(z)dz  \right ]=\int_{\gamma } g\cdot dr
$$

To be specific, may I ask the following questions:

1. Does $\int_{\gamma} g \cdot dr$ represent the work done required to move along the curve, given that a force $F=(u,-v)$ is acting on the moving point?
2. My lecture notes says that $\int_{\gamma} g \cdot dr$ represents the **circulation** of $g$, is circulation same as work done along a *closed* curve? I am confused since my lecture notes didn't say the curve $\gamma$ is closed.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In some contexts, you can interpretate it as the work done by a given force, but this is only valid if you consider your function $f(z)$ as a Force Vector Field. Is well known that a complex function $f(z)$ can represent physical situations, like Forces Fields, ElectroMagnetic Fields, Fluids, weather situations, etc. It all depends in the interpretation that you give to $f(z)$ (for example, if f(z) doesn't represent a force field, then $\int_\gamma g \cdot dr$ can be interpretate as the work done)
2. i'm not totally sure, but the circulation is a more mathematical definition or quantity than a physical one. And it's not necessary that the curve $\gamma$ has to be a close one.

Good luck in your futures learnings! I highly recommend this video to gain some intuition in the complex plane: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyBDtUtyshk&t=1936s&ab_channel=Mathemaniac It helped me in it's moment!